# why is esc_html() returning nothing given a string containing a high-bit character?

Tags: escaping, sanitization

In PHP 5.2, filter_var() sanitizes text.  In WP, esc_html() sanitizes text.  The former works with a high-bit character in the text string, e.g. à , but the latter doesn't.  esc_html seems to be totally eating a string containing a high-bit character.  Here's the example, written as a simple WP plugin:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: bugz tester
*/
class bugz_tester { 
    function __construct() {
        if ( ! is_admin() )
            return;

        add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this,'admin_page'));   
    }

    function admin_page() { 
        add_options_page('Bugz tester', 'bugz', 'edit_posts', 'bugz_sheet', array(&$this,'test_page'));
    }


    function test_page() {    
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
        <?php
        $ts = 'blah à blah';
        echo "original: " . $ts . "<br/>" ;
        echo  "PHP sanitized: " . $this->sanitize_txt( $ts ) . "<br/>" ;
        echo  "WP sanitized: " . esc_html( $ts ) . "<br/>";               
        die();
        ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    function sanitize_txt ( $text ) {
        $san_text = filter_var($text, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW ) ;
        return $san_text;
    }   

}
new bugz_tester();
?>
```

Here's the output:

> original: blah � blah
>   PHP sanitized: blah à blah
>   WP sanitized:

I'm not obsessed with using esc_html().  But if I use instead filter_var(), the string vanishes when I add it to a WP custom field. Somehow WP sanitation is killing the string.

I'm mystified.  Would be grateful for a clue.

Comment: Additional note:  Using the handy WP Debug console  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar-console/  I tried

Comment: I entered into the WP console 'echo esc_html('blah à blah');' which produced 'blah à blah'. So esc_html works differently in different contexts???? @chip-bennett

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps because the entity is a non-UTF8 character?

Here's what `esc_html()` does:

```
function esc_html( $text ) {
      $safe_text = wp_check_invalid_utf8( $text );
      $safe_text = _wp_specialchars( $safe_text, ENT_QUOTES );
      return apply_filters( 'esc_html', $safe_text, $text );
}
```

If not that, then it's getting sanitized when filtered by `_wp_specialchars()`, which does double-encoding(by default,no) and all sorts of things.

For reference:

1) `esc_html()` [in source](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/wp-includes/formatting.php.source.html#l2328)

2) `_wp_specialchars()` [in source](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/wp-includes/formatting.php.source.html#l278)

Comment: In the example above, &#224; is a UTF-8 character.  See

Comment: [à]  U+00E0    &#224;  LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE at http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/utf8-t1.html

Answer (score 0):

Using the [PHP filter_var() function with appropriate filters](http://us.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) does allow the sanitized text to be inserted into the meta field.  What's going on with esc_html seems to be some obscure character coding issue.

WordPress 3.2 will require PHP 5.2.  So, if you're having trouble with the WP esc_html() function, the PHP 5.2 filter_var is a good alternative.